# Visual Studio 2012 - location of Conditional Compilation Symbols settings

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, conditional-compilation

I cannot for the life of me find the field where I'm meant to input the conditional compilation symbols for a project in Visual Studio 2012. I'm new to this feature so I don't know if it's been renamed something else, but I'm trying to follow [this guide](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/451734/Visual-Studio-Use-Conditional-Compilation-to-Contr) but I get stuck at picture #4. I can't find a Build tab in the project properties, let alone the conditional compilation symbols field. I'm in a C++ project if that makes a difference.

I've looked in documentation and Googled it to no avail. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for making the question and the answer that shows up in Google.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so someone else I asked has found the solution:

1. Go to Project properties > Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Preprocessor
2. In Preprocessor Definitions click the drop-down arrow on the right and do `<edit>`.
3. Add the new definition to the text box on a new line.

Credit to user [Steve](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1197518/steve).

Comment: I don't see this option in VS2013 .. any ideas here?

Comment: Hi bc3tech, I just had a look and couldn't find the options! How annoying. I looked here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3600tzxa(v=vs.120).aspx and couldn't find the Configuration Properties tab it says to click.

Comment: I actually found where they define this in VS2013 and have used it in one of my recent blog posts: http://netitude.bc3tech.net/2014/07/14/localizing-your-app-name-tile-on-windows-phone/