# Define Conditional Compilation Symbols in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, preprocessor-directive

After reviewing "[Visual Studio 2012 - location of Conditional Compilation Symbols settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16721567/visual-studio-2012-location-of-conditional-compilation-symbols-settings)", I was unable to find the location of the Conditional Compilation Symbols box in VS 2013 for an ASP.NET web application.

Where can you define symbols based on the selected build configuration for an ASP.NET application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an ASP.NET web application, the location of the Conditional Compilation Constants option is slightly different.

***Project → Project Properties → Compile → Advanced Compile Options → Custom Constants***

It is still under the group heading of *Compilation Constants*.

[image: Screenshot of Advanced Compile Options dialog.]